# can a MVC 3 app execute an Action in a different app on the same server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two asp.net applications running on one server, one is MVC-3, the other is not.  the MVC application has a POST action which sends an email and returns a JSON object.  Can the plain asp.net application somehow execute the action (from server) and receive the JSON object? I guess it just needs to execute a POST somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:  It is the method HttpWebRequest, used as follows.

```
string data = "data to post";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("put URL here"); 
// set post headers
request.Method = "POST";
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(data);
writer.Close();
writer.Dispose();
// next line posts the data to the URL
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Thanks @erict for posting answer. I believe this is exactly what I need as well.